# Do companies want you to follow up all the time?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

Here are some facts about the company:

1. Large organization
2. Been to three interviews and been told by the recruiter that I am the front runner
3. Hiring manager has not been once clear about the hiring timeline despite being asked the question directly
4. I have already expressed my interest on multiple occasions that this job is my top choice
5. The hiring manager says that the need is immediate
6. They know I am interviewing at other places too

Do they just want the candidate to follow up all the time and push the agenda? Is that their way of having me showing interest? In other words, if I don't follow-up, nothing will happen?

Comment: If they flake out like this when your interviewing for the job, just think how much they will flake out after you get the job, do you really want to work for people who don't respect you enough to get back to you within a reasonable time?